# Fast Search Linked List not Compiling, needs return statement

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm given the following code below where I have several linked list manipulations. The one function I am focusing on is `searchFast()`. Before I compile the code I get a warning stating "no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]."

What I was thinking is that I add a `return NULL`. But that doesn't seem right.

See the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node{ //if you want to convert to class, you need to assign access specifiers to public since they're private on default

    int data;
    struct Node *next;

}*first = NULL;

void create(int A[], int n)
{

    struct Node *t; //create a temporary pointer t
    struct Node *last; //pointer, points to the last node - helps me add a new node at the END of a linked list
    //as of now, the linked list is empty, so we must create the first node!

    first = new Node;//create new node on the heap, and first will be pointing on that new node
    first -> data = A[0]; // Assign first the first element on the array
    first -> next = NULL;//Should point to a null value as it is the only element on the list to start/currently
    last = first; //last points on first node

    for (int i = 1; i <n; i++)// i starts at element 1 since first has been assigned the 1st element in the array
    {
        t = new Node; //create a new node
        t->data = A[i]; //fill up the data of t from A[i] which will be iterated through and assigned to data
        t->next = NULL; // the next node should be pointing to NULL, as there is nothing at the moment when the iteration begins that it is initially pointing to

        last -> next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

Node * searchFast( struct Node * p, int key){
    Node * q = NULL;
    while (p != NULL){
        if(key == p->data){
            q->next = p->next;
            p->next = first;
            first = p;
            return p;

        }
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void display (struct Node *p)
{
    while (p != 0 )
    {
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        cout<<p->next<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }

}

int main() {

    int A [] = {1,2,3,18,5, 6, 7};

    create (A,7);
    display(first);


    cout<<"If following value 18 can be found in the linked list, its address is the following: "<<searchFast(first, 18);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a return statement in the function searchFast().

Comment: ***What I was thinking is that I add a return NULL. But that doesn't seem right.*** I expect you need to return nullptr if not found and the node pointer if found.

Comment: The block after `if(key == p->data){` looks very odd. I would not expect this behavior in a search function.

Comment: @drscherjm OP needs a `return` for a successful search...so it should be `if (key == p->data) return p; else {`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding return NULL and return p, and the code successfully compiled.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;

    struct Node{ //if you want to convert to class, you need to assign access specifiers to public since they're private on default

        int data;
        struct Node *next;

    }*first = NULL;

    void create(int A[], int n)
    {

        struct Node *t; //create a temporary pointer t
        struct Node *last; //pointer, points to the last node - helps me add a new node at the END of a linked list
        //as of now, the linked list is empty, so we must create the first node!

        first = new Node;//create new node on the heap, and first will be pointing on that new node
        first -> data = A[0]; // Assign first the first element on the array
        first -> next = NULL;//Should point to a null value as it is the only element on the list to start/currently
        last = first; //last points on first node

        for (int i = 1; i <n; i++)// i starts at element 1 since first has been assigned the 1st element in the array
        {
            t = new Node; //create a new node
            t->data = A[i]; //fill up the data of t from A[i] which will be iterated through and assigned to data
            t->next = NULL; // the next node should be pointing to NULL, as there is nothing at the moment when the iteration begins that it is initially pointing to

            last -> next = t;
            last = t;
        }
    }

    Node * searchFast( struct Node * p, int key){
        Node * q = NULL;
        while (p != NULL){
            if(key == p->data){
                q->next = p->next;
                p->next = first;
                first = p;
                return p;

            }
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    void display (struct Node *p)
    {
        while (p != 0 )
        {
            cout<<p->data<<" ";
            cout<<p->next<<" ";
            p = p->next;
        }

    }

    int main() {

        int A [] = {1,2,3,18,5, 6, 7};

        create (A,7);
        display(first);


        cout<<"If following value 18 can be found in the linked list, its address is the following: "<<searchFast(first, 18);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `q->next = p->next;
                p->next = first;
                first = p;` is still wrong. All you want to do is return `p` nothing else. No changing of the nodes. No resetting the head pointer.